# Defining vairable inside xcode & use it in WebView

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am interested in knowing if we can define variables inside xcode & then access it in HTML or javascript.

for e.g. 
Define a variable in xcode like this

```
NSString * abc = @"Hi there!";
```

and access it in Baker or phonegap like this

```
<script>
var xyz = xcode.abc //XCode 
alert(xyz);
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you want to define objects in Objective C and then retrieve their value in javascript?